# Remove or change width and height attribute for Trix Editor uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

So I'm using Basecamp's Trix editor for a Ruby on Rails project.

What I'm trying to do is make the uploaded/ attached image fit to the width of its parent.

Trix automatically embeds the height and width of the image on the element itself.

Any way I can stop trix from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you supplied your code, I can give you an exact answer. But what you can do is target the elements with CSS and then set the rendered dimensions thus:

```
.col-sm-10 a {
  text-align: center;
  img {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block; #ensures the caption renders on the next line     
    }
```

where `.col-sm-10` is the class enclosing the `<a>` tag which in turn enclosed the `<img>` tag. Of course, the `class` will be different depending on your HTML.

Use ***inspect*** on your browser to determine the relationship.

Good luck.

---

**UPDATE:**

A better method would be to target the image like so:

```
#post-show-body a {
  text-align: center;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize the height and width of the attached image, you can simply add trix-content class to your trix-editor tag. And then make sure also to include the class into the result div. From there you can adjust trix-content class from your application stylesheet as usual.

The other way  is to copy the trix stylesheets folder and play around with .attachment and img tag from within the content.scss

The following is how mine looks like:

```
img {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

.attachment {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   max-width: 50%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Read **Styling Formatted Content** https://github.com/basecamp/trix

Answer (score 0):

In your `\app\assets\stylesheets\actiontext.css` you can define the image properties.

Mine looks like this.

```
.trix-content img {
  max-width: 70%;
  height: 450px;
}
```